# Continuous linear operator that is NOT compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

**Exercise:**

Let $U:L^1(0,\infty)\to L^{\infty}(0,\infty)$, defined as \begin{equation}U(f)(x):=\int_0^x f(t)dt\end{equation} Prove that $U$ is linear, continuous but **not compact**.

**My solutions** (or what I managed to show):

$U$ is linear is quite trivial. $U$ is continuous: let $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence in $L^1(0,\infty)$ converging to $f$. To show: $\lim_{n\to \infty}U(f_n)(x)=U(f)(x)$. Since $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^x f_n(t)dt=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, $U$ is continuous.

To show that $U$ is no compact, I have some troubles:

**My question:**

I tried to start by considering $f_n:=\mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}$ so we have $\Vert f_n\Vert_1=1$ and I define $g_n:=U(f_n)$. Then what I want to show is that $g_n$ cannot contain any Cauchy-Subsequence. How can I show this? Thank you in advance

Comment: No: it does: $\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}=\int_n^{n+1}1dx=1$

Comment: Sorry, I thought it said $1_{[1,n]}$ for some reason.

Comment: For continuity, you could also show boundedness since the operator is linear. To show boundedness, just note that:
$|U(f)(x)| \leq \int_0^x |f(t)| dt \leq \int_0^\infty |f(t) | dt = \|f\|_{L^1}$.

Comment: @Peter your proof of the continuity is correct. OP's is not: He/she has only shown pointwise rather than uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Fix any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, show that for any $m>n+1$, we have $\|g_n-g_m\|_{\infty} \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $g_n$ is weak-$*$ convergent.

Comment: Ok Thank you @tomasz. I tried with your hint: Assume at contreriory that it is compact: then since $\lim_{n\to \infty }<U(g_n),f>$ exists and is finte for every $f\in L^1$ and since $(L^1)^{\ast}$ is isometrically isomorsphic to $L^{\infty}$. we have that .... No I don't get it. I wanted to use the fact that $L^1$ is not separable :/

Comment: @MorganeMaPh: But $L^1$ *is* separable. In any event, that is hardly relevant. My point was that $g_n$ weak-$*$ converges to zero, so any norm convergent subsequence would also have to converge to zero, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: ok I see the idea. But why does $g_n$ weak$^{\ast}$ converges to zero?

Comment: @MorganeMaPh: There are a few ways to see that. For instance, you can just check it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If $n > m$, then for $x\in [m+1/2,m+1]$,
$$
g_n(x) = 0 \text{ but } g_m(x) = x-m \geq 1/2
$$
Hence,
$$
\|g_n - g_m\| \geq 1/2 \quad\forall n\neq m
$$
so it can't have a Cauchy subsequence.

Comment: Great! thank you @Prahlad Vaidyanathan!

Comment: But wait: why is $g_n(x)=0$? $m+1/2$ may be between $n$ and $n+1$.